# Reading Lightwave LWO binaries, UV problem

Tags: binary-data, ieee-754, chunks, uv-mapping

Okay, so I'm trying to make CSHARP Lightwave 3D model converter to convert my LWOs into a Javascript object. So far I have the guts of the program working, and I'm please. But I've run into trouble with exporting UVs from the binary file.

This is my reference material for the LWO binary:
http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/LWO

For testing purpose I'm using single square model with two triangles, with six points. So as you might already be familiar with, I get to the Texture UV chunk which looks like this in HEX (with annotated commas, and Ascii translated):

```
[V] [M] [A] [P]
00  00  00 4C

[T] [X] [U] [V]
00 02
[t] [e] [s] [t] [.] [p] [n] [g]
00 00
00 00, 3E FD FD FD, 3E FD FD FD,
00 01, 3F 2A FD FD, 3E FD FD FD,
00 02, 3E FD FD FD, 3F 2A FD FD,
00 03, 3F 2A FD FD, 3E FD FD FD,
00 04, 3F 2A FD FD, 3F 2A FD FD,
00 05, 3E FD FD FD, 3F 2A FD FD
```

Now, according to the documentation I linked about, that translates to the below. If you want to translate this yourself, this is a handy tool, I find, for translating a 32 bit HEX into a IEEE 754 Single float.

http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatApplet/IEEE754.html

LWO UV binary translated:

```
VMAP
76
TXUV
2
test.png
0
0, 0.4960784, 0.4960784
1, 0.6679380, 0.4960784
2, 0.4960784, 0.6679380
3, 0.6679380, 0.4960784
4, 0.6679380, 0.6679380
5, 0.4960784, 0.6679380
```

See, this looks healthy enough until you compare the UV positions to the actual positions in Lightwave:

```
0, 0.3333333, 0.3333333 or (33.33333%)
1, 0.6666667, 0.3333333
2, 0.3333333, 0.6666667
3, 0.6666667, 0.3333333
4, 0.6666667, 0.6666667
5, 0.3333333, 0.6666667
```

You can see, the binary file isn't that far off, but it's enough to make all the difference, especially when intension is to export thousands of these buggers. Now I can see no pattern in this discrepency.

My current theory at the moment is that the numbers aren't in IEEE754 format. But all other values are, so why would these be different. Is there something I'm missing? For a little further help, here are some other test values.

```
Lightwave  => Binary
0.00000000 => 0.00000000
0.25000000 => 0.49414062
0.40000000 => 0.49607840
0.50000000 => 0.50000000
0.70000000 => 0.70000000
1.00000000 => 1.97656250
```

It appears some are correct, and others are just... so very wrong. Thanks for taking the time to read this question, I appreciate that it's very long and dense with numbers. Any help would be fantastic!`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Lightwave sdk from http://www.newtek.com/lightwave/developers.php .
It includes a complete documentation on the .lwo format.

EDIT:

Lightwave stores all it's data in Big Endian. So you have to swap the bytes before interpreting them as float.